# Is it possible to override disk space and memory settings with the Cloud Foundry task scheduler?

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev, appcloud

The document at https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/devguide/using-tasks.html describes how to use Cloud Foundry tasks. The document at https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-offerings/task-scheduler.html describes how to schedule tasks.

When running tasks, we can override the global disk size and memory settings for a single task by the parameters -k and -m.

It seems that we can't pass these parameters along a scheduled task, or maybe we just didn't find this in the documentation. Anybody can shed some light on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to override these parameters. You can do that when you bind the service:

```
cf bind-service my-app my-scheduler -c '{"schedule":"0 2 * * *", "task":"rake cleanup-database", "memory_in_mb":"value", "disk_in_mb":"value"}'
```

We will extend the documentation with an example.